# Adding more than one role to a user after registring in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roleprovider

in my web site, i have three roles(Editor , Reviewer and Author)
In some situations I need to add my user all 3 roles by coding. how can i do that?
an also how can i update my user roles? thank you very much
please guide me.

```
 MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(email, "123456",email);
 Roles.AddUserToRole(email, "Editor");
```

Comment: Add code on how you are setting/updating roles.

Comment: I don't know how to update! but here is the cod that shows how to add one role:   
 MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(email, "123456",email);
 Roles.AddUserToRole(email, "Editor");

Comment: Have you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertoroles.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add user to multiple roles use [Roles.AddUserToRoles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertoroles.aspx) like this

```
Roles.AddUserToRoles(email, new string[] {"Editor", "Reviewer", "Author" });
```

I do not know about a method that updates an existing role. But you can always [delete a role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.deleterole.aspx) and [add a new role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx) instead.

Comment: how should i fill it with new string?